# How do I create a loop such that if the cell in a table contains characters, it will automatically create another row of cell

Tags: vba, ms-word

The table is in MS WORD but I am trying to use VBA to loop it. Currently I have data extracted from a source and would like to input in a table in MS word. The table contains multiple rows and 2 columns. The data would be input inside the second column of each row. Right now, I have many data and it is impossible for me to keep on specifying each row number, hence I want to find a way to add an additional row whenever the cell is filled.

In Excel, this set of codes would work but not in word..

```
 Do While (Len(Worksheets("Overall Performance").Cells(NewRecordRow, 12).Value) <> 0)
     NewRecordRow = NewRecordRow + 1
 Loop
```

Currently this is what I have.

```
Dim intNoOfRows
Dim intNoOfColumns
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objRange
Dim objTable

intNoOfRows = 1 (Initially 6 because I Preset it)
intNoOfColumns = 2

Set objWord = CreateObject ("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Document.Add

objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns

Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
objTable.Borders.Enable = True

For Each cell(intNoOfRows,2) in objDoc.Table(1).range.cells
    If Len(cell.range.text) <1 Then
        intNoOfRows = intNoOfRows + 1
    End if
Next

ObjTable.Cell(intNoOfRows,2).Range.Text = "ABC"
```

Comment: Can you please explain your question and code, because it is unclear of what you want to do here.

Comment: Currently I have data extracted from a source and would like to input in a table in MS word. The table contains multiple rows and 2 columns. The data would be input inside the second column of each row. Right now, I have many data and it is impossible for me to keep on specifying each row number, hence I want to find a way to add an additional row whenever the cell is filled

Comment: you can always edit your question, and insert this explanation there so that everybody can read your question thoroughly.

Comment: In Excel, this set of codes would work but not in word..                                    
 Do While (Len(Worksheets("Overall Performance").Cells(NewRecordRow, 12).Value) <> 0)
     NewRecordRow = NewRecordRow + 1
  Loop

Comment: Where is your data coming from? It sounds like you just want to create a Word table, with a row for each row in your source data. Is this correct? If so, it's likely there's a much easier way to do what you want to do.

Comment: In what format is this data? Can you get a count of the number of items you need to insert?

Comment: I am getting data from a banking system. However, the amount of data extracted is not fixed, hence I need to loop the row. And yes, the data contains words and numbers and it can be counted.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my test, the following code works well on my side(The key point is **InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )**).

```
 Do While InStr(1, strCellText, "", vbBinaryCompare) <> 1
           'MsgBox "OK"
          Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1
    Loop
```

Worked full code(For test purpose, manually Create a table of N rows and three columns first):

```
Sub Test()
Dim intNoOfRows
Dim intNoOfColumns
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objRange
Dim objTable As Word.Table
Dim strCellText As String

intNoOfRows = 1 '(Need to be the actully row count of your talbe)
intNoOfColumns = 3

Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
objTable.Borders.Enable = True

With objTable  

 strCellText = .Cell(intNoOfRow, 2).Range.Text
 intNoOfRows = .Rows.Count

    Do While InStr(1, strCellText, "", vbBinaryCompare) <> 1
           'MsgBox "OK"
           intNoOfRows = intNoOfRows + 1
    Loop      

.Rows.Last.Select
Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1

.Cell(intNoOfRows, 3).Range.Text = "ABC"
MsgBox intNoOfRows
End With
End Sub
```

You also can use the following code, but this will run into memory issue so it is not recommended:

```
With objTable
Do While Len(.Cell(intNoOfRows, 2).Range.Text) <> 0
     intNoOfRows = intNoOfRows + 1
     MsgBox intNoOfRows
Loop
End With
```

Comment: There is an error in the first line that you input. There is an error message for the .Range where it says it is a compile error: invalid or unqualified reference.

Comment: You can see the "With objTable" in the full code, you need to add it to the first line. I have edit the code.

Comment: I used the code below and there are no errors, but no new row is being created.                                                                                             With objTable                                                                                                    
  For Each c In .Range.Cells
    'MsgBox .Cell(intNoOfRows, 2).Range.Text
    If Len(.Cell(intNoOfRows, 2).Range.Text) <> 2 Then  
       intNoOfRows = intNoOfRows + 1
    End If
Next

Comment: The code above just update the No of rows. To create new row, we just need to execute something like Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1

Comment: There is an error in the "selection.InserRowsBelow 1". It says  "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: You can use the Record Macro feature to add new row to table and check the script on your side.  Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1 works well on my side