# Automatically create another row in a table whenever the row is filled up

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently manually typing row by row in order to input data. EG.

```
objTable.Cell(1,2).Range.Text = "A"
objTable.Cell(2,2).Range.Text = "B"
objTable.Cell(3,2).Range.Text = "C"
```

Is there a way where I can loop them? 
The end product should be

```
objTable.Cell(x,2).Range.Text = "A"
objTable.Cell(x,2).Range.Text = "B"
objTable.Cell(x,2).Range.Text = "C"
```

Comment: `objTable.Rows.Add` will add a new row, and you can do that in a loop.

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried to loop it but I can't seem to do it..  Do while objTable.cell(intNoOfRows,2). Range.Text > 3 objTable.Row.Add Loop

Comment: How is this data stored / how or from where are you reading it? Are you creating the entire table, or appending to an existing table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a loop such that if the cell in a table contains characters, it will automatically create another row of cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868780/how-do-i-create-a-loop-such-that-if-the-cell-in-a-table-contains-characters-it)

Comment: The data is stored in a variable i created such as S1, S2, S3. I am creating an entire table and only add a new row if the current row is filled.

Answer (score 0):

If we have create a table, and just use the following code to create a new row:

```
existedTable.Rows.Last.Select

Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1
```